# Trying to Authenticate with Google OAuth and get error "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-authentication, google-oauth

I am trying to create a Node.js authentication service to authenticate with the Google OAuth api.

I have this code:

```
private exchangeTokens(code: string): Rx.Observable<IAuthTokens>{

    code = decodeURIComponent(code);

    console.log(`exchanging code for tokens: ${code}`);

    const redirectUri = "http://localhost:8080";

    let url = YouTubeAuthenticationServer.baseUrl + "token";

    var postData= "code=" + encodeURIComponent(code);
    postData += "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(redirectUri);
    postData += "&client_id=" + encodeURIComponent(process.env.CLIENT_ID);
    postData += "&client_secret=" + encodeURIComponent(process.env.CLIENT_SECRET);
    postData += "&scope=";
    postData += "&grant_type=authorization_code";

    return this.makePostRequest<IAuthTokens>(url,postData);
}

private makePostRequest<T>(targetUrl:string, data: string): Rx.Observable<T>{

    console.log(`getting targetUrl: ${targetUrl}`);

    var urlObject = url.parse(targetUrl);

    var options: http.RequestOptions = {
        hostname: urlObject.hostname,
        port: Number(urlObject.port),
        path: urlObject.path,
        protocol: "https:",
        method: "POST"
    };

    const request = https.request(options);

    const returnObservable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(<any>request, "response")
        .take(1)
        .flatMap( response => RxNode.fromWritableStream(<any>response))
        .do( data => console.log(`data pumped: ${data}`) )
        .toArray()
        .map(function(allData){
            return JSON.parse(allData.join("")) as T;
        });

    console.log(`write data: ${data}`);

    request.write(data);
    request.end();

    return returnObservable;
}
```

and from this I get the following logs:

```
exchanging code for tokens: 4/k6Pp7jCPDms2meo0qfINqs0c9FZSjJ7PvGp8mdnh3Y8#
getting targetUrl: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
write data: code=4%2Fk6Pp7jCPDms2meo0qfINqs0c9FZSjJ7PvGp8mdnh3Y8%23&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&client_id=myCorrectId&client_secret=myCorrectSecret&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code
data pumped: {
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

So I am sending the following:

```
code=4%2Fk6Pp7jCPDms2meo0qfINqs0c9FZSjJ7PvGp8mdnh3Y8%23
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080
client_id=myCorrrectId
client_secret=myCorrectSecret
scope=
grant_type=authorization_code
```

So I can't understand why it is saying that I am not sending grant_type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many many thanks to [João Angelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204699/jo%C3%A3o-angelo) for this answer (posted in a comment below)

Make sure that the request contain this header: 
`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
as Google may allow other content types and might be misinterpreting the payload.

The code now looks like this:

```
private makePostRequest<T>(targetUrl:string, data: string): Rx.Observable<T>{

    console.log(`getting targetUrl: ${targetUrl}`);

    var urlObject = url.parse(targetUrl);

    var options: http.RequestOptions = {
        hostname: urlObject.hostname,
        port: Number(urlObject.port),
        path: urlObject.path,
        protocol: "https:",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    };

    const request = https.request(options);

    const returnObservable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(<any>request, "response")
        .take(1)
        .flatMap( response => RxNode.fromWritableStream(<any>response))
        .do( data => console.log(`data pumped: ${data}`) )
        .toArray()
        .map(function(allData){
            return JSON.parse(allData.join("")) as T;
        });

    console.log(`write data: ${data}`);

    request.write(data);
    request.end();

    return returnObservable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify a `scope` then don't append `"&scope="`. The server may be interpreting your request as asking for a scope of:

```
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Which would then mean the request does not actually contain a `grant_type`.

Comment: I only added scope as that's what is passed on the example on the Google OAuth playground. It does not work when that is removed either.

Comment: Also make sure that the request contain this header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as Google may allow other content types and might be misinterpreting the payload.